# Easiest way to delete rows with a column value matching value in separate file list?

Tags: python, csv

I have two files, file1 is a csv with several hundred rows and 12 columns, file2 is a list with several hundred values.

What is the easiest way to compare each value from file1, col(0) to each value in file 2, then delete the file1 row if there is a match to any value in file2?

I tried using this code to do the matching part, but get a syntax error, I think because python will not allow two concurrent readers:

```
initialAvail = open('py_all1.csv')
Reader1 = csv.reader(initialAvail)
data_list1 = list(csv.reader(initialAvail))
IpodPLexcl = open('ipod_py.csv', 'a') 
Reader2 = csv.reader(IpodPLexcl)
data_list2 = list(csv.reader(IpodPLexcl))

for i in range(1, len(data_list1)):
        Reader1item = int(data_list1[i][0])
        for j in range(1, len(data_list2)):
                Reader2item = int(data_list2[i][0])
                if Reader1item == Reader2item:
                        compareMatch = True
                        print(compareMatch)
```

Do I have to do a dictionary (since the second file is just a list, not a csv with multiple cols)?

Comment: Split the problem up: 1. read files in memory. 2. apply rules. 3. if there exist changes then overwrite original file.

Comment: Maybe you are right since these files are smaller than the original ones before this step. Will try that.

Comment: Off-topic: I strongly suggest you read and start following the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) guidelines for naming things, especially [variable names](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#prescriptive-naming-conventions).

Comment: Have a look at pandas library to manipulate tables in python. A few hours and you will save many hours in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are open to use pandas library, a simple code as this would give you the desired result:

**Assuming**: py_all1.csv is the file we want to remove rows from.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('py_all1.csv') # file with multiple columns
df2 = pd.read_csv('ipod_py.csv') # file with one column

mask = df1.iloc[:,0].isin(df2.iloc[:,0])
df1[~mask].to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
# change output.csv to 'py_all1.csv' if desired output
```

I tried it with this sample data:

```
file1_data = '''\
A,B
New York,1
Paris,2
London,3
'''

file2_data= '''\
A
New York
Paris'''

with open('py_all1.csv','w') as f1, open('ipod_py.csv','w') as f2:
    f1.write(file1_data)
    f2.write(file2_data)
```

And the result is:

```
A,B
London,3
```

Comment: Outstanding. I am not smart enough to understand the documentation, so I appreciate this example. If I now understand it...

Comment: What if, instead of deleting rows based on matching data, as in `mask = df1.iloc[:,0].isin(df2.iloc[:,0])` you delete rows with an offset value from df1, like column 2? Another way of putting it is output a list of col 2 values from df1 for those rows where df1 col 0 and df2 col 0 match.

Comment: OK, you just have to remove the tilde as in `mask = df1.iloc[:,2].isin(df2.iloc[:,0])
df1[mask].to_csv('output.csv', index=False)`, then you can use the resulting file the same way as in the first example.  Pandas is great!

Comment: One other related question...in your example `file1_data = '''\
A,B
New York,1
Paris,2
London,3
''' ` these values appear only once.  If under file1_data they appear multiple times, the code does not remove all of the values.  Is there a fix for that?

Comment: @user3447273 Ok, wait so the only question right now is your last one. I don't see any problem in that, the code should effectively remove all items that are in the first column of file2. If you can provide a sample I can most likely help. By searching for "{my problem} pandas" you will most likely find an answer here on SO (there are tons of questions).